# Fabricjs textbox for large text content stuck in first line

Tags: fabricjs

In fabricjs textbox if text content(no space) is larger than the textbox width it won't go to next line, it stuck at first line. So that I get the content width using `text:changed` event and try to press `enter` programmatically if content is greater than textbox width but its not working. Is there any other way?

I don't want to override fabricjs default method for breakwords it has other conflicts and cursor get misplaced.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text1 = new fabric.Textbox('Text', {
  left: 10,
  top: 20,
  width: 300
})

canvas.add(text1);

canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
  if (e.target.width > 300) {
    console.log("text over width");
    $('#canvas').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {
      keyCode: 87,
      which: 13
    }));
  }
});
```

```css
canvas{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox of Fabric.js does not wrap a long word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858237/textbox-of-fabric-js-does-not-wrap-a-long-word)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37858237/3551786)

Comment: Cursor get misplaced check in fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/pratyush141/59p71exh/

Comment: Thats why I mention "don't want to override fabricjs default method for breakwords"

Comment: Yes that was only work arround till now, nothing solved for word break. In 2.0 grapheme(http://fabricjs.com/fabric-text) introduced.