# Fabric js textbox wrap a long word

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using a customized textbox which should maintain the same width for a textbox while splitting a long word into a new line (I have modified the solution initially proposed by one of the library's maintainers). You can find the code in the following link.
The `_wrapLine` function is overridden.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/njofce/0qfb3snm/

The problem is, when the word is too long, it splits into lines, but the cursor is not correctly positioned.

Any ideas to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Yuyutsu No, the bug is still there.