# How to stop in Text overflow width?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I need to know why my text is always `overflow`.
I would like to hide it when it `overflow`

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

var text = new fabric.Text("Bharatasdsaasdasda\nnn\nklssd", {
    fontFamily: 'Courier New',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    fontSize: 16,
    fill: '#000000',
    scaleToWidth: 2.8
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#ffcc12',
});

var group = new fabric.Group([rect, text]);
canvas.add(group);
text.width = 10;
canvas.renderAll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vx8c5qeL/

Comment: overflow: hidden, will not work!

Comment: Okay sorry, I have not seen the jsfiddle link

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858237/textbox-of-fabric-js-does-not-wrap-a-long-word

Comment: @ProgrammerPer thanks for your advice, i try it. But i seen that the "function" doesen't work any more. I get following Erro `this._measureText is not a function`. it's funny because measureText is a fucntion fo js

Comment: @Remo I could take a look later to see if I can find a better solution

Comment: @ProgrammerPer will be very lovely, special thanks =)